# dpHibernate: serializerFactory not initialized by Spring -> NullPointerException on service access

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, blazeds, spring-integration, dphibernate

I am trying to get dpHibernate 2.0 RC6 running on an Apache Tomcat 7.0.12 with BlazeDS 4.0.0.14931, Spring 3.0.5 and Spring-BlazeDS-Integration 1.5.0.M2

With the following configuration the server starts fine, but as soon as I want to access a service or the RDSDispatchServlet via FlashBuilder4 DCD I am getting a NullPointerException. It seems the serializerFactory is not correctly injected into the dpHibernate HibernateUtil. Did I miss something in the configuration in remoting-config.xml?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
          version="2.5">

   <display-name>Server</display-name>
   <description>Server Side based on BlazeDS, Spring and Hibernate</description>
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <!-- begin SPRING INTEGRATION -->
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>springMessageBroker</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <!-- <init-param> -->
     <!-- <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> -->
     <!-- <param-value></param-value> Do not use if using ContextLoaderListener (would load app context twice -> Error) -->
     <!-- </init-param> -->
     <init-param>
        <param-name>services.configuration.file</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMessageBroker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- end SPRING INTEGRATION -->

  <!-- begin rds -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>useAppserverSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>        
    <init-param>
        <param-name>messageBrokerId</param-name>
        <param-value>_messageBroker</param-value>
    </init-param>        
    <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CFIDE/main/ide.cfm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- end rds -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>dpHibernateSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.dphibernate.filters.HibernateSessionServletFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>dpHibernateSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml** (Spring Servlet default configuration file)

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="flexContext.xml" />
    <import resource="dataAccessContext.xml" />
    <import resource="dpHibernateContext.xml"/>

    <!-- Enable Spring Transaction Manager with Annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations" value="/WEB-INF/server.properties" /></bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myproject.*" />
</beans>
```

**flexContext.xml** (definitions of services available for flex)

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd">


    <flex:message-destination id="chat"/>

    <flex:message-broker services-config-path="/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml">
            <flex:remoting-service default-adapter-id="dpHibernateRemotingAdapter" default-channels="my-amf,my-secure-amf" />
            <flex:message-service default-channels="my-streaming-amf,my-polling-amf"/>
    </flex:message-broker>
</beans>
```

**fpHibernateContext.xml** (configuration of dpHibernate)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"  
      xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd        
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                          ">
  <!-- Defines the remoting adapter, which intercepts inbound & outbound messages, and routes them thruogh dpHibernate -->
  <bean id="dpHibernateRemotingAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.flex.core.ManageableComponentFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg value="org.dphibernate.adapters.RemotingAdapter" />
    <property name="properties">        
      <value>
      {"dpHibernate" :
        {
          "serializerFactory" : "org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory"
        }
      }
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="dpHibernateMessagingAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.flex.core.ManageableComponentFactoryBean"> 
    <constructor-arg value="org.dphibernate.adapters.MessagingAdapter" /> 
  </bean> 

  <bean id="dataAccessService" class="org.dphibernate.services.SpringLazyLoadService" autowire="constructor">
    <flex:remoting-destination />
  </bean>

  <!-- Required -->
  <bean id="hibernateSessionFilter" class="org.dphibernate.filters.SpringHibernateSessionServletFilter" />

  <!-- The cache is used to prevent serializing the same object many times during serialization.  Required -->
  <bean id="dpHibernateCache" 
    class="org.dphibernate.serialization.DPHibernateCache" scope="prototype" />

  <!-- The main serializer. Converts outbound POJO's to ASObjects with dpHibernate proxies for lazy loading.  Required -->
  <bean id="dpHibernateSerializer"
    class="org.dphibernate.serialization.HibernateSerializer" scope="prototype">
    <property name="pageSize" value="10"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="dpHibernateDeserializer" class="org.dphibernate.serialization.HibernateDeserializer" scope="prototype" />
  <!--  Handles entity updates (CRUD).  Required if using entity persistence. -->
  <bean id="objectChangeUpdater" 
    class="org.dphibernate.persistence.state.AuthenticatedObjectChangeUpdater" 
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="preProcessors" ref="dpHibernatePreProcessors" />
    <property name="postProcessors" ref="dpHibernatePostProcessors" />
  </bean>   
</beans>
```

**remoting-config.xml** (imported in services-config.xml)

```
<service id="remoting-service" 
         class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService"
         messageTypes="flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage">

  <adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="hibernate-object" class="org.dphibernate.adapters.RemotingAdapter" default="true">
      <properties>
        <hibernate>
          <sessionFactory>
            <class>org.dphibernate.utils.HibernateUtil</class>
            <getCurrentSessionMethod>getCurrentSession</getCurrentSessionMethod>    
          </sessionFactory>
        </hibernate>
      </properties>
    </adapter-definition>
    <adapter-definition id="java-object" class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter"/>
  </adapters>

  <default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
  </default-channels>
</service>
```

**NullPointerException** (on service access or rds access via FB4 DCD)

> startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
>   11.04.2011 18:34:19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Initializing Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext 1027 [Thread-2]
>   INFO
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>   - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final 1066 [Thread-2] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment -
>   Hibernate 3.6.2.Final 1074 [Thread-2]
>   INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment -
>   hibernate.properties not found 1085
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment -
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist
>   1116 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using
>   JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
>   2146 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration -
>   Hibernate Validator not found:
>   ignoring 2182 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister
>   - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener
>   on the classpath. Hibernate Search is
>   not enabled. 2194 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory
>   - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   2658 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Database ->
>          name : MySQL
>       version : 5.0.51a-24+lenny5-log
>         major : 5
>         minor : 0 2658 [Thread-2] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Driver ->
>          name : MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
>       version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 (
>   Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
>         major : 5
>         minor : 1 2861 [Thread-2] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using
>   dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
>   2981 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory
>   - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
>   2991 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory
>   - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of
>   read-write or transactional
>   second-level cache is not recommended)
>   2991 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Automatic flush during
>   beforeCompletion(): disabled 2991
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Automatic session close at end of
>   transaction: disabled 2991 [Thread-2]
>   INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - JDBC batch size: 20 2991 [Thread-2] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled 2998 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Scrollable result sets: enabled 2998
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled 2998
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Connection release mode: auto 3003
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2 3003
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Default batch fetch size: 1 3003
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Generate SQL with comments: disabled
>   3003 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Order SQL updates by primary key:
>   disabled 3003 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Order SQL inserts for batching:
>   disabled 3003 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Query translator:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   3023 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 3023 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Query language substitutions: {} 3023
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
>   3023 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Second-level cache: enabled 3023
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Query cache: disabled 3029 [Thread-2]
>   INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
>   3074 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
>   - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
>   3084 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Optimize cache for minimal puts:
>   disabled 3084 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Structured second-level cache entries:
>   disabled 3131 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Echoing all SQL to stdout 3138
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Statistics: disabled 3138 [Thread-2]
>   INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled 3138 [Thread-2]
>   INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
>   - Default entity-mode: pojo 3138 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Named query checking : enabled 3138
>   [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory -
>   Check Nullability in Core (should be
>   disabled when Bean Validation is on):
>   enabled 3239 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
>   - building session factory 3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [blob] overrides
>   previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.BlobType@17f7be7b
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [java.sql.Blob]
>   overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.BlobType@17f7be7b
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [materialized_clob]
>   overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@9fa8988
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration
>   [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides
>   previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@1f5b44d6
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [clob] overrides
>   previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.ClobType@21044daf
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [java.sql.Clob]
>   overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.ClobType@21044daf
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [characters_clob]
>   overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@21882d18
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration
>   [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides
>   previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@734893da
>   3282 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry -
>   Type registration [materialized_blob]
>   overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@21e30857
>   3379 [Thread-2] INFO
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory
>   - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
>   11.04.2011 18:34:36 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'springMessageBroker'
>   11.04.2011 18:34:36 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8080"]
>   11.04.2011 18:34:36 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>   11.04.2011 18:34:36 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   start INFO: Server startup in 21332 ms
>   11.04.2011 18:49:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SCHWERWIEGEND:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [RDSDispatchServlet] in context with
>   path [/myJavaServer] threw
>   exception
>   **java.lang.NullPointerException**    at
>   **org.dphibernate.utils.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory**(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.dphibernate.filters.HibernateSessionServletFilter.getSessionFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.dphibernate.filters.AbstractHibernateSessionServletFilter.doFilter(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**org.dphibernate.utils.HibernateUtil** (snippet)

```
private static ISerializerFactory serializerFactory; // should be injected by Spring

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws HibernateException
{
    return serializerFactory.getSessionFactory(); // but is null on this call?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remotingConfig.xml isn't needed, and appears to be what's causing your problems.

Typically, in a Spring configuration, the `HibernateUtil` class you've shown there isn't used (the `SpringContextSerializerFactory` returns the SessionFactory to ensure you're getting the correct one from your Spring session)

However, it looks like your remotingConfig.xml file is overwriting the default settings, forcing it to use the old `HibernateUtil` approach, which is throwing your NPE.

Comment: Works! Thanks a ton! Unfortunately having solved this leads me to another problem. As this is probably not related I opened another thread, would be glad if you could help me with that as well, cause I can't find much on the net. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648428/spring-blazeds-integration-illegalargumentexception-servletcontext-must-not-be