# spring blazeds integration: IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, blazeds, spring-integration, dphibernate

I am trying to get dpHibernate 2.0 RC6 running on an Apache Tomcat 7.0.12 with BlazeDS 4.0.0.14931, Spring 3.0.5 and Spring-BlazeDS-Integration 1.5.0.M2

I got pretty far with my configuration, the services are parsed fine, annotation based Entities and Datamodel are good, I can list the services in FlashBuilder DCD, but as soon as I am calling a service method (just a simple void method) the server returns following Exception. Not really sure where in my configuration I could have missed something, as I understood from the docs the rest is auto wired.

```
{operation})****************getAll
{invoke} 6823
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:82)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getContextReference(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:111)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializerContextReference(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:65)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializer(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:56)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializer(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:51)
at org.dphibernate.adapters.RemotingAdapter.invoke(RemotingAdapter.java:132)
at flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingService.java:183)
at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java:1400)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:1005)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a3ef066.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:572)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dafba90.serviceMessage(<generated>)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dafba90.service(<generated>)
at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[BlazeDS]Exception when invoking service 'remoting-service': flex.messaging.MessageException: ServletContext must not be null
incomingMessage: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage) 
operation = getAll
clientId = E8B0A041-2F0D-95A8-1F38-D5D244CDA6E4
destination = personService
messageId = 499B6C51-8E26-DD96-9055-79EF0D3823B0
timestamp = 1303420800415
timeToLive = 0
body = 
[

]
hdr(DSId) = E8B03010-7B0F-DED7-6D71-C4623D635D2A
hdr(DSEndpoint) = amf
Exception: flex.messaging.MessageException: ServletContext must not be null
at flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingService.java:225)
at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java:1400)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:1005)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a3ef066.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:572)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dafba90.serviceMessage(<generated>)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dafba90.service(<generated>)
at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ServletContext must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:82)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getContextReference(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:111)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializerContextReference(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:65)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializer(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:56)
at org.dphibernate.serialization.SpringContextSerializerFactory.getSerializer(SpringContextSerializerFactory.java:51)
at org.dphibernate.adapters.RemotingAdapter.invoke(RemotingAdapter.java:132)
at flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingService.java:183)
... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, finally I could narrow it down to FlexContext.getServletContext(); returning "null" in SpringContextSerializerFactory.java line 110 (dpHibernate current "2.0" branch, springExtensions 3.0).

Quick fix to this (staying compatible to the current implementation) was altering the code to look like the following:

```
    ServletContext servletContext = FlexContext.getServletContext();
    if(servletContext == null) // fix for Servlet Context must not be null exception during migration to Spring 3.0
        servletContext = FlexContext.getMessageBroker().getServletContext();
    context= WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

Don't know if I am doing something ugly here, but works for me. Just thinking ... this line attempts to get the webapplication root context via the current servletContext, if this is null just get it via another one that must be there if this request gets here (which is the springMessageBrokerServlet).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a dpHibernate issue, as it is an issue with your Spring/Web.xml config.  As such, please consider this a best guess, as there are others around who know a helluva lot more than I.

It appears you're missing the `<context-param />` section from your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
               /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

That snippet is taken from [one of the samples](http://code.google.com/p/dphibernate/source/browse/trunk/samples/lazyLoadingWithSpring/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml) on the dpHibernate site

The error you're seeing is caused by a missing SpringContext which is needed by dpHibernate in order to look up your Hibernate session.

Comment: Thats been my first guess as well. In the meantime, after flicking through the same example you posted, I tried this approach, but to no avail. I'm still getting the same error. Any other clues? Seems to be one of the last hurdles to a working system setup.

Comment: Do you have an `applicationContext.xml` defined?

Comment: Yep, see in the original post (third box).

Comment: As far as I understood the applicationContext.xml is the default for Spring in when located at /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, that would explain why the extra parameter in web.xml does not change anything, unless it does not have any effect at all.

Comment: This is a tough one.  I notice that in your question, you reference `fpHibernateContext.xml`, I assume this is just a typo, and the file is actually named `dpHibernateContext.xml`?  Are you able to create a simple sample project, and log a defect on the dpHibernate site?

Comment: yep, dpHibernateContext.xml was a typo in the post. Regarding the sample project ... as you said this is not specifially a dpHibernate issue, so I opened an issue on the spring-blazeds-integration tracker ... https://jira.springsource.org/browse/FLEX-194 ... testapp included

Comment: think I finally got it ... flexContext.xml etc have to be imported in springMessageBroker-servlet.xml, not in applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, need to reopen ...

I configured my application mostly like the lazyOverflow sample. But when I call my own service to populate my ArrayCollection PM I keep getting this ServletContext Error. Sample is the call to getRecentQuestions() from RecentQuestionPM via LoadRecentQuestionsCommand and the according result handler in RecentQuestionPM.

http://code.google.com/p/lazyoverflow/source/browse/trunk/flex/src/com/mangofactory/pepper/view/RecentQuestionsPM.as

Server Configuration is now exactly the same as in the sample, just with my own Entity, DAO and Service names.

Thats as far as I could track the problem:

```
SpringContextSerializerFactory:111
ServletContext servletContext = FlexContext.getServletContext();
--> servletContext --> null
```

Comment: I isolated the problem in an example project, posted in the spring integration forum. Seems to show up only when using spring 3.0.5 instead of 2.5.6 ... see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/FLEX-194